# Выдает исключение при попытке открыть файл на чтение объекта

Tags: java, файлы

Файл находится по пути:

```
E:\programming\project\java\manager\out\production\data\dirlist.dat
```

Открываю файл:

```
File flist = new File(data_dir  + "filelist.dat");
File dlist = new File(data_dir + "dirlist.dat");
FileInputStream rfile = null, rdir = null;
ObjectInputStream ofile = null, odir = null;
rdir = new FileInputStream(dlist);
odir = new ObjectInputStream(rdir);
```

Но код выдает исключение IOException. Метод getLocalizedMessages() выдает null, метод toString() - StreamCorruptredException: invalid stream header 00000000

В чем проблема?
Файл спокойно открывается на запись, но не на чтение. С другим файлом та же история
Так и не понял в чем проблема, но создал файлы не в каталоге проекта - помогло

Comment: У исключения кроме типа есть еще сообщение. И что такое `getLocalizedMessages`?

Comment: getLocalizedMessage()* - возврат локализованного возврата описания исключения

Comment: Именно в данном случае - нету. Только null. Создал такой же файл в другой папке - открывает. Сейчас еще просмотрю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Причиной данного исключения с кодом 00000000 является необходимость открыть файл на запись объекта в этот файл как минимум 1 раз, прежде чем его открывать на чтение.